# foreach statement cannot operate (GetEnumerator) Please help me

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop

Cannot assign to 'cell' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

```
foreach (var cell in cells)
  {
      var temp = cell * 0.3048;
        // convert  to meter
      // cell = cell * 0.3048;
        if (temp < Fluid)
        {
            double layer = Fluid - temp;
            if (layer > based)
            {
                layer = based;
            }
            double value = gridSize * gridSize * layer;
            totalValue += value;
        }
    }
```

and I have another error again related to this part: 
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'double' because 'double' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
`private double[] volumcalculate(double cells, double gridSize, double based, double Fluid) 
     {

   // 1. cubic meter, 2. cubic feet, 3. barrels

    double[] values = new double[3]; 
    if (cells==null){
    return values; 
        double totalValue = 0;
    // convert  to meter
    gridSize = gridSize * 0.3048;

  foreach (var cell in cells)
  {
      var temp = cell * 0.3048;
        // convert  to meter
      // cell = cell * 0.3048;
        if (temp < Fluid)
        {
            double layer = Fluid - temp;
            if (layer > based)
            {///
```

and I get cell and cells from the following part:

```
 public List<double> readFileToList(string Path)
    {

        var cells = new List<double>();
        string path = label3.Text;

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            double temp = 0;
            cells.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(path)
                .Where(line => double.TryParse(line, out temp))
                .Select(l => temp)
                .ToList());
            int totalCount = cells.Count();
            cellsNo.Text = totalCount.ToString();

        }

       return cells;

    }
```

and

```
  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            label3.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            // textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(label3.Text);

            string path = label3.Text;
          readFileToList(path);

                                     }enter code here
```

Comment: @GrantWinney   this line foreach (double cell in cells)
      {

Comment: That line doesn't appear in your question.

Comment: @GrantWinney I am in kind of rush to deliver this code. If it is possible tell me where is the problem.

Comment: @AvaNm: Great.  Now please show us the definition of `cells`.

Comment: @Dan-o: var cells = new List<double>();

Comment: ALso, check your sample in the method for loading the cells....that appears to be a bit interesting at first glance with the use of TryParse in the Where

Comment: its like pulling teeth getting details out of you.  So now are we to assume that somewhere before your `foreach` in the first code **fragment** you assign cells to the result of `readFileToList` ?  Come on, quit fooling around and show us all the relevant code.

Comment: @Dan-o but I post all relevant code :(.

Comment: @GrantWinney please have a look at my edited code.

Comment: @Dan-o How about know?

Comment: Wow.  I'm gonna have to agree with @GrantWinney.  Go grab a C# tutorial.

Comment: @Dan-o Sorry but I do not have a time, I have two hours to send this code. I am wondering if you can help me. many thanks

Comment: Nope.  You're on your own.

Comment: @Dan-o at least tell me where is the problem. could you? pleaesssss.:((

Answer (score 1):

Based on the commentary here and the deleted comments, in your definition it seems that cells is not a List but just a double.

High level example would look like this

```
var cells = new List<double>;
foreach(var cell in cells)
{
    var toWorkWith = cell * 0.3048;
    //Rest of code here
}
```

Assuming that you will actually fill cells with a value rather than just setting it to a new list.  If this doesn't work, inspect your type for the cells object